# Convert text blurbs into bullets inside multiple excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like below in my excel cells:

[image]

I want to convert this to bullets. How to do that?

I tried using Alt+Enter on each cell and it works fine but I have so many cells. How to achieve the below structure:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `=SUBSTITUTE (A1,"->",CHAR(10)&"->")` and format as text wrap?

Comment: tried that. not working :(

Comment: Because the cell contains over 255 characters?

Comment: Nope. I doubt that

Comment: the alt+enter thing is working but there are so many cells

Comment: Judging by your screenshots it's all in one cell

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTIfF.jpg